# How to replace a lambda with a method reference

Tags: java

I am getting this warning on SonarQube: "Replace this lambda with a method reference."

The code is :

```java
childrenNames = StreamSupport.stream(favouritesFolder.getChildren().spliterator(), false)
    .map(node -> node.getName())
    .limit(NUMBER_OF_FILES_TO_DISPLAY)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I replace the lambda with a method reference in my case?

Comment: Since there's only one lambda in your post I'd assume it needs to be something like `Node::getName` (or whatever the type of `node` is).

Comment: What IDE are you using? Usually you should get a warning or a hint at which line you should replace the code

Comment: I use Eclipse. the code has no problems and it's functioning as expected but i think the SonarCube has problems with lambdas, this is why i had to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue by assigning the type of the node which is in my case `CmisObject` as following:

```java
childrenNames = StreamSupport.stream(favouritesFolder.getChildren().spliterator(), false)
    .map(CmisObject::getName)
    .limit(NUMBER_OF_FILES_TO_DISPLAY)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

`node -> node.getName()`=>`Node::getName`